# Applying a Band-pass filter on the iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, algorithm, ios, ipad

I am developing an application where I need it to analyze the incoming frequency with the built-in microphone on the iphone/ipad. I know that I need to use FFT and I have found a framework that can help me on that. My only concern was is there is a code or framework that includes Band-Pass filtering? Suggestions are welcome.

**EDIT**
Pardon my ignorance. I previously posted that I wanted to use just a Band-Pass equation, when I found out that Band-pass is both Low & High Pass filters. I still welcome suggestions.

Comment: What kind of analysis do you need to do?

Comment: Then you probably don't need separate high-pass or low-pass filters to do frequency band vocal analysis.  More likely windowed FFTs, cepstrums, or various types of autocorrelation.

Comment: If it's a real-time application, you should do it in time domain, not FFT domain. If you're trying to convolve two long signals, FFT is the way to go.

Comment: I should have mentioned that it's real-time. I figured that with I would need a band-pass filter since I need to avoid sounds from ambient surroundings.

Answer (score 2):

You can always do this yourself using a biquad filter.

Here's a great document explaining how they work and what coefficients you need to plug in to create a bandpass filter: http://musicweb.ucsd.edu/~tre/biquad.pdf

Comment: Would it be possible to just enter both low pass and high pass filter equations? Cause I was unst informed that a band-pass filter is both filters being implemented together

Comment: The Doc I linked to has the biquad coefficients for a bandpass filter, which is much more efficient than running a hi-pass followed by a lo-pass.  You can indeed do Hi-pass followed by Lo-pass however.. that is what the BPF coefficients are basically encapsulating.

Comment: This link is broken.

Comment: Try this one instead then: http://www.earlevel.com/main/2013/10/13/biquad-calculator-v2/

Answer (score 1):

On iOS 4.x, there is the built-in Accelerate vDSP framework for FFT and convolution.  But unless you want to build on top of the FFT or convolution routines, there is nothing built-in for band-pass filtering.  Fast convolution filtering using an FFT for overlap add/save can be very efficient, depending on your filter kernel requirements and the signal length.